# Adaptive Neural Network in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to configure an adaptive neural network in simulink. I based it on the paper in the link.
[text](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0925231211002141?via%3Dihub)

The one I tried to create failed. I would really appreciate it if you could give me the code for the neural network.

Comment: Please share what you tried and why did it fail. People are here to give help, not to do the work for others for free